# See if User is Verified on Firebase Dashboard

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am able to send verification emails to users that sign up. And with the iOS SDK I am able to check if their email is verified or not.

However, is there anywhere on the Firebase backend / dashboard where I can see this value or change it? Similar to my other data.

Comment: I don't think the value is visible in an API or UI, except for the logged in user. You *can* however check it in your code and security rules. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986097/how-can-we-guarantee-that-the-email-saved-by-the-firebase-user-is-indeed-his-own/37994216#37994216).

Comment: I don't think there is such value but you can just create that in your user database