# Firebase allowing only the creator to post

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I've been working on a blogging app for my personal website, and I want to only allow myself to post new blog posts, but allow all the logged in users to add comments to the posts.

Here is currently how a data looks like:

```
"posts": {
  "-KpZlH9PYs7mAf8avBmI" : {
    "comments" : {
      "-KpZwWIrbM3JQ2ug1c5_" : {
        "message" : "How are you today?",
        "timestamp" : 1500637173055,
        "user" : "Florin Pop"
      },
      "-KpZyxoC0OTxnDZymP-M" : {
        "message" : "I'm fine, thank you!",
        "timestamp" : 1500637814102,
        "user" : "Florin Pop"
      }
    },
    "likes" : 0,
    "text" : "asxszx",
    "timestamp" : 1500634227427,
    "title" : "qwqew"
  }
}
```

As you can see a post has: **a list of comments**, **likes**, **text**, **timestamp** and **title**.

I'm not sure if the structure is the best for what I want.

Is there way I can check if I'm the currently logged in user and only then allow for creating a new post?

Should I have the comments separately?

**P.S.**

Currently my database rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you make the following changes:

In the root of the database create a new object `admins`, the users who can edit/create posts:

```
"admins": {
    "<ADMIN_1_UID>": "true",
    "<ADMIN_2_UID>": "true"
}
```

Then make changes to your security rules like this:

```
"rules": {
    "admins": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false /*This ensures that only from firebase console you can add data to this object*/
    },
    "posts": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val()" /*This ensures only admin can write post stuff*/
        "$postId": {
            "comments": {
                ".write": "auth != null" /*This overrides the above write rule and allow authenticated users to post comments*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do I get my own UID?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile

Answer (score 1):

> Should I have the comments separately?

Even without knowing all the details of your app, the answer is almost certainly "yes". Having different entity types in different top-level nodes often drastically simplifies the security rules of your database.

> Is there way I can check if I'm the currently logged in user.

In security rules you can check if the operation is coming from **a** authentication user with `auth != null`. But your JSON contains no UID as far as I can see, so it's not clear to me who **the** current user is.

Comment: Well... I have ```auth != null``` currently, but that allows all the users to create blog posts on the website. And I only want to allow myself to do that. Is there a way I can check that by email or github?

Comment: I added the rules I have at the moment in the question above... That ensures that only authenticated users can add comments to the posts.

Comment: To access the email address in your security rules, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986097/how-can-we-guarantee-that-the-email-saved-by-the-firebase-user-is-indeed-his-own

Comment: and this is the best approach to check if the user is me for the blog app?

Comment: Do I need to store all the users in Firebase database?

Comment: Since May 2016 the email address is available in your security rules as `auth.token.email`. You don't need to store anything in the database for that.