# How to structure a Firebase admins list

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to make a list of admins in firebase. Admins users should be able to add other admins, by email.

Ideally, I'd like a "list" like this:

```
"admins": {
  "a.b@gmail.com": true,
  "c.d@gmail.com": true
}
```

This would allow me to easily add new admins by email, and to use useful authentication rules 
 (that verify users [by email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986097/how-can-we-guarantee-that-the-email-saved-by-the-firebase-user-is-indeed-his-own)), like this :

```
".write": "root.child('admins').child(auth.email).val() === true"
```

But I can't use a list like that, because Firebase [restricts special characters in keys](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-creating-references).

How can I solve this?

My application is client-side javascript (so I can't use [firebase-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every registered user has a firebaseID, so I would structure your data this way:

```
"users": { // Here you store user's data
    "firebaseID1": {
        "email": "a.b@gmail.com"
    },
    "firebaseID2": {
        "email": "c.d@gmail.com"
    }
},
"admins": {
  "firebaseID1": true,
  "firebaseID2": true
}
```

If you want to get the ID of a user given its email you can use firebase's [queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference):

```
firebase.database().ref("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo("a.b@gmail.com")
```

**NB**: firebase.com is the old website, for the updated documentation always look at [firebase.google.com](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)

Comment: Nice! How would you go about creating the "users" list? Every user writes himself when he logs in? Or can it be generated automatically somehow? @devid

Comment: You can let every user create his own entry at first login using security [rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) to avoid users setting wrong emails. You can also use [cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) with a firebase auth trigger :)

Comment: Small typeo: "equalsTo" [should be](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) "equalTo" @Devid