# Firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I would like to be able to have my database only accessible from 3 Google  domains. I can access it from one domain but when I try to add more it fails.

The rules I have tried so far:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth.token.email.endswith('mycompany@gmail.com')"
    } 
}
```

I have tried to add an or statement into it but with the second domain I don't get authorised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try playing with this syntax instead:

```
"auth.token.email.matches(/.*@gmail.com$/)"
```

You can put logical operators inside as well - `&&`, `||`.

---

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986097/how-can-we-guarantee-that-the-email-saved-by-the-firebase-user-is-indeed-his-own) and *obviously* [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Comment: Thank you Michal :) I will give it a go.

Comment: No have not been able to get it work it works for the first one but when adding in the second it does not work:(